# i'd like to do awscli with Cygwin terminal python

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, anaconda

I wanted to use awscli with Cygwin, window7.

So I typed `pip install awscli` and succeeded the install.

But when I type `aws`, I got an message

`C:\Users\k\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users/k/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I don't know what is `cygdrive`,first of the path.

So I tried `cygstart/C/Users/k/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws`

but it also didn't activate with error msg `Unable to start 'C\Users\k\Anaconda2\Scripts\aws': The specified file was not found.`

I don't know how should i do

Comment: your anaconda pyhton installation does not know the cygwin style https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive. It seems you have mixed the two python installation anaconda and cygwin one.

Comment: thanks to you, i solved the problem, thank you matzeri